# Repeating a navigation command in vi

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, vi

How do I repeat a navigation command in vi?

For example, I execute the command `20j` which moves the cursor down 20 lines, and I tried hitting `.` to repeat that command, but it says "No command to repeat".

P.S. Also, what command goes to the next page in a document?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There isn't a shortcut to repeat the last navigation command - you have to retype it, or set up some sort of shortcut of your own (`:map` or similar).

Page up (back) is <kbd>Control-B</kbd>; page down (forward) is <kbd>Control-F</kbd>.  Half-pages are <kbd>Control-U</kbd> (up) and <kbd>Control-D</kbd> (down).

Comment: Is there a reason that the repeat command doesn't work on navigation commands? Why this design decision?

Comment: @Chetan: because the change commands are usually more complex.  Besides, if you're searching, you can use 'n' or 'N' to jump to the next or previous match - which is a short cut for searches, I suppose.  For my work, I most frequently use the n's, or jumps such as '`[[`' or '`]]`' to find the start of a function, or '`{`' or '`}`' to find paragraphs.  Or I use a map to coordinate both the change position and change data.