# How do I repeat any command in Vim, like "C-x z" in emacs?

Tags: vim, command, repeat

In Vim, is there any way to repeat the last command regardless of whether it was an edit or not, and without having the foresight to first record a macro?

E.g. say I type `:bn`, and want to do it again (it was the wrong file). Pressing `.` obviously doesn't do it. Or maybe I'm doing `gE` and want to repeat that (with one keystroke since clearly `gE` is kinda painful to type).

Perhaps there are some plugins? Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3671019/repeating-a-navigation-command-in-vi).

(Even cooler would be to retroactively bind a number of commands to a macro, so one could type `5qa@a` or something to repeat the last 5 commands...)

Answer (score 97):

To repeat a command-line command, try `@:`, To repeat a normal/insert-mode command, try `.`,

Add below mapping to your .vimrc if you want to shortcut the same:-

`:noremap <C-P> @:<CR>` - This will map Ctrl+P to previous command-line command. You can map any other combo.

Comment: So how about normal-mode commands like "gE"? There's a ":norm" command for executing normal-mode commands from the command line, but it doesn't repeat...

Comment: what does `gE` do anyways ? i tried `dw` to delete a word, and then i pressed `.` to delete another word

Comment: It's a motion command, "Backward to the end of WORD", the reverse of E.

Comment: ctr+P is used for autocompletion of code, so you probably don't wont to remap it to that

Comment: Ctrl+P is also mapped to the so-known plugin CtrlP

Comment: autocomplete mapping is usually insert mode mapping (imap), so you can use nmap if you only want to enable a map when in normal mode.

Comment: That's great. I checked the docs as well, and even though the `:` register doesn't ordinarily contain a <cr> or newline char, it seems that running `@:` is different from other registers' macros in that `@:` explicitly repeats the last command instead of simply replaying what's in the `:` register, like `@a` would.

Answer (score 16):

`:help repeating` will provide the typical repeat commands (like ., @:, etc.). You could try [repeat.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2136). That may get you closer to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 13):

For motion commands there is no mechanism built into Vim.  The Find and To commands (`f`/`F`/`t`/`T`) have `;` and `,` to repeat and reverse.  There are a couple of plugins which extend those bindings to repeat other motion commands:

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2174

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3665

The later should support repeating `gE` using `;`

Answer (score 12):

You can just use "."

Example: 
You have "abc" at 10 places in your file and you want to replace it with "def" at 5 places of it.

Step 1: Find first occurance of abc by typing command "/abc" 
Step 2: Once cursor is on "abc", Replace abc by command "cw" to take out word "abc"

Step 3: Type in "def" as replacement and press enter to go to command mode

 Step 4: To repeat this action just type command "n" to go to next occurrence of abc **and type command "."** . **The command remembers that you replaced "abc" with "def" last time and will perform the same here.**

Answer (score 3):

You can map `@:` to some key for more convenience:

```
:map <F2> @:
```

and then it's easier to use it with repeats.